How can rotation about Z be a superposition of rotations in X ($|\uparrow \rangle_z = |\uparrow\rangle_x + |\downarrow\rangle _x $)
I am fully aware of the mathematical
form that relates spinstates when measured from different axes. For example the unnormalized relation: $$|\uparrow_z \rangle = |\uparrow_x \rangle + | \downarrow_x \rangle ,$$
But my feeling is that I don't have a physical understanding of why spins exhibit this feature.
For example, in a quantum mach zhender interferometer, it's clear how the probability amplitudes interfere and that the state can be thought as mixing two different modes.
But for spins, it's not so clear to me what physically is happening in a measurement of spin in the $z$-direction that leads to this indeterminate uncertainty in the $x$-direction.
Please do not confuse this as me not having familiarity with the standard calculations of QM. For example, yes I am aware that $S_x$ doesn't commute with $S_z$ and that their commutator can be used to explicitly solve for the projective operator between basises.
I'm trying to understand physically why making a measurement of Sz causes Sx to be in a superposition.
Other systems are easier to understand what is happening quantum mechanically . Take polarization of photons of light for example: $|A\rangle$ and $|D\rangle$ are incompatible basises because they are simply quantum superpositions of $|V\rangle$ and $|H\rangle$.
Based on current answers:
I am aware of the empirical fact that $|\uparrow_z \rangle = |\uparrow_x \rangle + | \downarrow_x \rangle ,$ and the experiments that prove its existence. What I am trying to understand is how this can be understood as a physical system that is in a quantum system of two different rotations. What is "first-principles" reason why rotation about the z-axis is a quantum superposition of clockwise and anti-clockwise rotation about the x-axis??

Does it help thinking about angular momentum instead, being motion through space rather than an intrinsic dof?

No $\sqrt{2}$ normalization?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer, yeah but I can't visualize how rotating clockwise and anticlockwise in x produces clockwise motion in z

@Qmechanic, I'm on my phone so formatting everything perfectly is difficult

What you are "trying to understand" does not make sense to me. What do you mean by "a physical system that is in a quantum system of two different rotations." Rotations are not states.

@FlatterMann The sense in which the OP uses "rotations" is pretty self-evident.  I don't think throwing hifalutin unitary requirements is really helpful here.

@ZeroTheHero Unitarity (plus independence) is what leads to superposition, normalization, the use of complex numbers and generally all kinds of rotations in vector and Hilbert spaces. The wave function always rotates, whether angular momentum is involved or not.

Think about spin as an internal degree of freedom, similar to the polarization of an electromagnetic wave. This is the approach taken to explain the Stern-Gerlach experiment at the start of Sakurai's "Modern Quantum Mechanics". You can check that resource out for a longere explanation. Here's a simplified version.
Consider an initially unpolarized EM wave travelling in the $y$ direction. Let it go through a linear polarizer in the $z$ direction. The polarizer selects this component of the electric field. Now, imagine you let this polarized wave through another liner polarizer, but such that it's axis is in a diagonal. Something like
$$\vec{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\hat{x}+\hat{z} \right). $$
As you can see, this direction can be written in terms of the $\hat{z}$ vector, it's not orthogonal to the $z$ direction. Therefore, the polarized wave will go through it, while lowering its intensity. The wave has "regenerated" the $x$ component that it previously did not have.
This is very similar to what is observed in the Stern-Gerlach experiment. You can think of this experiment as a way to observe the spin of a beam of coherent particles. If you first let the beam through a SG apparatus in the $z$ direction, it will measure spin in this direction. The quantum state will be "polarized", it will be $|S_z,\pm\rangle$. Experimentally, if this beam now goes through a SG apparatus in the $x$ direction, it will select a spin component in this direction, the state will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|S_x,\pm\rangle$. This is akin to letting the $z$ polarized wave through the diagonal polarizer.
In other words, the experimental results are explained thinking about spin as an internal degree of freedom such that any spin state can be constructed as a linear combination of spin states in some other direction. That is, the $|S_z, \pm\rangle$ state is
$$|S_x,\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|S_x,+\rangle \pm |S_x,-\rangle \right). $$
It's easy to notice that the two situations are not fully equivalent because in the EM wave case you're measuring along a diagonal axis, and in this case you're measuring along the $x$ axis (orthogonal to the original one). You've probably heard that spin states are invariant under $4\pi$ rotations (if you haven't, you may interested in looking into that further). You can use this to interpret the results further. The orthogonal to a spin state is not the spin state in the spatially orthogonal direction, it's the spin state in the opposite direction: $|S_x,+\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|S_x,-\rangle$, not to $|S_z\rangle$ states.
Ultimately, this is a consequence of the different spin operators having an eigenbasis that is also a basis of the spin Hilbert space (which, in this case, is essentially the $C^2$ vector space). Therefore, all the directions you can measure spin in offer a potential choice of basis.

This seems like the answer that I was trying to explain that I am already aware of. I am famiar with the SG experiment and the empirical fact that $S_z$ is a superposition of up and down in the X-basis. As you've said in your answer (and as I asked in my question), the polarization of light is a much more clear situation because the being in the diagonal direction $|D\rangle$ is literally being in a combination of the other degrees of freedom ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|H\rangle + |V\rangle$). For $S_z$ it's not clear to me how this physically consists of a superposition of up and down from $S_x$.

Maybe you're answering my question here: "The orthogonal to a spin state is not the spin state in the spatially orthogonal direction, it's the spin state in the opposite direction: $|S_x,+\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|S_x,-\rangle$, not to $|S_z\rangle$ states."
But I don't quite see what you mean here exactly.

Or putting it a different way: how does a superposition of clockwise and anticlockwise in X make Z?

(I’m sorry to say) there is so much confusion in the title and the post…
First, a rotation about $\hat z$ is not a superposition of rotations about $\hat x$.  In fact, what you have written has nothing to do with rotations:
$\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ is a state, not a rotation.  When you write
$$
\vert \uparrow_z\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vert \uparrow_x\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vert \downarrow_x\rangle \tag{1}
$$
you write one state as a linear combination of other states, just like you would write any vector as a combination of basis vectors.  There is no rotation of anything in (1).
A measurement of spin in the $\hat z$ direction gives one of two possible values: either spin up or spin down, or if you prefer the numerical answer, either $\pm \hbar/2$.
If you start with the state $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ and send your particles in a SG magnet with field gradient along $+\hat z$, you will get spin up 100% of the time, i.e. every measurement will give $+\hbar/2$.  That’s what the labelling tells you. Basically, in a SG experiment with field grading along $+\hat z$, all particles described by the state $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ would be deflected up by an amount that is the same as the deviation of a particle with magnetic moment $\vec \mu$ oriented along $\hat z$ but with magnitude half of what you’d expect if the particle had some angular momentum $+\hbar$. (You need to connect magnetic moment with angular momentum in the classical E&M way for this interpretation.)
Now, back to the choice of basis.  First, what is immensely counterintuitive is that, even if $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ and $\vert\downarrow_z\rangle$ are “classically” antiparallel, they map to orthogonal vector in spin space. In other words, the angle between the two vectors is not $\pi$ but half of this: $\pi/2$.  Even if the direction $\hat x$ is classically at an angle $\pi/2$ w/r to $\hat z$, again you need to divide the angle by $2$ to understand how states $\vert \uparrow_x\rangle$ and $\vert\downarrow_x\rangle$ are actually at an angle $\pi/4$ w/r to $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ and $\vert\downarrow_z\rangle$.  You need this funky half-angle to reconcile the outcomes of experiments with the math.
Next, the choice of basis is tied to the question you ask through the postulates.  When you express a state as a linear combination of $\vert \uparrow_x\rangle$ and $\vert \downarrow_x\rangle$, you are basically asking about probabilities of measuring the spin along the $\hat x$ axis.  The particular linear combination you have tells you that, if you measure spin along $\hat x$ (by passing your state through a SG apparatus with field along $\hat x$), the probability of a particle described by $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ going “up $+\hat x$” or “down $-\hat x$” is the same.  In other words, even if the particle would be deflected along $+\hat z$ all the time, it would be deflected along $+\hat x$ half the time and along $-\hat x$ the other half of the time.
Now you might well argue that $\vert \uparrow_z\rangle$ is not the only state for which you have these probabilities, and you are right.  The state $\vert \uparrow_z)\sim \vert \uparrow_x\rangle - \vert \downarrow_x\rangle$ yields the same probabilities as the one you have.  The phases are fixed by a consistency check: we understand how rotation act in our 3D space so we fix the phases so that, when rotating basis states, the results can be understood as a corresponding rotation of axes in 3D space.
This is really well covered in the textbook by John Townsend: a modern approach to quantum mechanics.  Townsend was clearly inspired by the treatment of Sakurai, who himself was influenced by Feynman.
